# Unexplained null pointer reference, I'm blaming ghosts

Tags: c#, mono, monomac

I've got the following code:

```
public void DrawInput(string ChatCurrent){

        int uCursorTop;
        int uCursorLeft;
        uCursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
        uCursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, uCursorTop);
        Console.Write("> "+ChatCurrent+" ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(ChatCurrent.Length, uCursorTop);
    }
```

Except for the final line, it behaves properly. The final line throws `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. The weird thing? Specifically, accessing `ChatCurrent.Length` is what's making it fail. The line immediately before, which echoes the string's contents, works just fine.

What's going on?

Comment: How are you calling this function, what is the source of ChatCurrent?

Comment: It's passed by reference from the main thread, which in turn initializes it in a separate class. I figured out the problem, it's stupid, please see my answer below so you know why to mail flaming dog waste to my doorstep.

Comment: And what does the line before output? String concatenation does not throw on `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what was happening:

I got the error as described above. When I commented out the Length measurement, I typed stuff in to see if the text would cause the error too. When it didn't, I put it back and tried other experiments.

I was consistently not typing anything while I tested, which in turn meant that the variable was declared but not initialized. I have been trying to fix this problem for **two hours.**

**To wit, in case someone else has this problem:** Make sure that your variable is **initialized.** It's as important as declaring it in this context.

Comment: So the essence of this answer is that you should initialize a variable to avoid a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: The essence of the answer is that one should initialize a variable to avoid a NullReferenceException, __and__ that just because you think a variable is initialized doesn't mean it is.

Comment: Local variables must be initialized or the code doesn't compile, and fields get initialized implicitly. This means it is impossible to read an uninitialized variable in C#.

Comment: The variable wasn't local. It was passed by reference from the main thread which set, and then loaded it from, another class.

Comment: The essence of the answer is that one should sleep more.

Comment: That's the honest to God truth. I'll take that advice.

Answer (score 9):

String concatenation will treat `null` values as **empty string**

> In string concatenation operations, the C# compiler treats a null
>   string the same as an empty string, but it does not convert the value
>   of the original null string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx

But even if you would pass `null` directly to `Console.Write`, it won't throw an exception, it will just write nothing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcwe8sfx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> If value is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), nothing is
>   written and no exception is thrown.

Comment: That's the ridiculous thing. `Console.Write` actually writes out text when I invoke it but comment out the line containing `ChatCurrent.Length`. I'm going insane.

Comment: @sudowned: of course it writes text: "`>  `". Whereas `ChatCurrent.Length` throws an exception because you cannot access a property of a null reference.

Comment: Yeah, it was writing the text **and the text I'd typed that was supposed to be in the buffer.** This is stupidity, this is entirely my own stupidity, but it's not what you think. See the answer I left.